# IBInspectable button inside IBDesignable view

Tags: ios, swift

I have an IBInspectable button inside IBDesignable view.
I tried several things but my icon is not displayed when I run my program.
The worst is : I can see it on storyboard inside my view but when I run icon is not set.

What am I doing wrong, I don't understand

```
@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {
   @IBOutlet weak var firstIcon: UIButton!

    //Not working
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
      let designTimeBundle = Bundle(for: CustomView.self)

      let image = UIImage(named: "home", in: designTimeBundle, 
      compatibleWith: nil)

      firstIcon.setImage(image, for: .normal)
   }
   //Not working either
   @IBInspectable var firstButtonIcon: UIButton {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: CustomView.self)
    let image = UIImage(named: "home", in: bundle, 
    compatibleWith: nil)
    firstIcon.setImage(image, for: .normal)

    return firstIcon
   }

   //And still not
   @IBInspectable var firstButtonIcon: UIButton! {
    firstIcon.setImage(UIImage(named: "home"), for: .normal)

    return firstIcon
   } 
}
```

Comment: I also avoid to have computed var for IBInspectable properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will never work. First read documents about how to use `IBInspectable`. It will work for `UIImage`, `UIColor`, `Float`, `Int`, `Double` etc typed variables. It never works for `UIButton` typed variables. Also, if you are using them with `IBDesignable` to show in storyboard, then you must have to have getter and setter for the same.

I suggest you should read some good tutorial or document about how and when to use `IBDesignalbe` and `IBInspectable`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Oops okay, I'll find another way to do it